# Find a relation between the sum of $100$ positive numbers and the sum of their pairwise products

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

> For positibe real numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{100}$, let
>   $$p=\sum_{i=1}^{100}a_i \quad \text{and} \quad q=\sum_{1\le i<j \le 100} a_i a_j$$
>   Then
>   (A) $q=\dfrac{p^2}2$ (B) $q^2\ge\dfrac{p^2}2$ (C) $q<\dfrac{p^2}2$ (D) none of the above

I took the first $100$ natural numbers. I have evaluated $p$ but how do I evaluate $q$?

Comment: Evaluate $p^2$ instead, and remember that $a_i$ could be anything, not necessarily the $i$th natural number.

Comment: @Arthur Can you explain furthure

Comment: If you are going to post a screenshot, at least crop it to reasonable size. Can be done with any image editor, or on a site like http://www.picmonkey.com

Comment: @ArthurHow to evaluate $p^{2}$

Comment: @NormalHuman Okay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: using binomial expansion, you get $p^2-2q = \sum_{i=1}^{100} a_i^2$.

By evaluating the latter, you can figure out what $q$ is.  However, in this case, that is not even necessary: all you need is, the relationship between $p^2$ and $2q$.

Comment: Can you explain first line in detail please

Comment: @TaylorTed We have $$p=a_1+\cdots+a_{100}\\p^2=(a_1+\cdots+a_{100})^2=a_1^2+\cdots+a_{100}^2+2q$$just by pure calculation. Sit down and write it out for ten instead of a hundred, and you can see why.

Comment: Thanks, you beat me to it.

Comment: @Arthur So answer is C ?

Comment: Yes, by multiplying by 1/2 and moving q to the other side.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$(a+b)^2 > 2ab$$

and $$(a+b+c)^2 > 2(ab+bc+ca)$$

Can you follow this up with induction?